# Problems on getting started with Oracle 11g Login issues and doubts

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I just finished up installing 11g on my laptop and I got a link which showed up the login page. The installation did ask me for a password and that does work for `system`.

So, I tried logging in to sqlplus using command prompt like this :

```
 sqlplus / as sysdba
```

which gives the error : `insufficient privileges`, but it did ask me for username and password after that to which I typed in `system` as `username` and the password I used at the time of installation.

Now it does log me in but I don't have privileges for more privileged commands.

I thought I should login as `sys` but I get error like : `connection as sys should be as sysdba or sysoper`.

Just give me a start on how I can login and how I can start interacting with my database right on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

your current operating system user must be either a privileged user (e.g. root in Linux "Administrator" in Windows) or must be part of the DBA group, otherwise you are not allowed to login without credentials.

If you don't want to change the current OS user, you need to supply the username and password on the commandline:

```
sqlplus sys/password as sysdba
```

The user `SYS` is special because you can **only** log in `as sysdba` with that user. On the other hand the `SYSTEM` user is **not** allowed to login as sysdba.

---

Btw: I hope you didn't plan to use `SYS` or `SYSTEM` to play around with Oracle. You should never create any tables in those schemas. Create a new user and use that to create tables and basically "use" Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Use user SYS (as SYSDBA) with password you specified during installation.

Comment: Tried that. Getting the error mentioned above : `connection as sys should be as sysdba or sysoper`

Comment: Ok wait. i was doing it the wrong way. Got that working. Thanks.